# How to fix table row no being clicked after append function?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to create a new table row every time the associated button is clicked. However, once I click the button and I go to select the row, it does not get highlighted. I have an `append` function that passes a `<tr>` to the html. My end goal is to have the the new row that was appended become clickable and can be selected.

**Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 left-pane">
  <div class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <button class="btn btn-sm btn-block eNew">New Tier</button>
  </div>

  <hr>
  <table class="table table-sm table-hover tAdd">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>IIS</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btnD">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SQL</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btnD">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Windows File Share</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btnD">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Etc</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-sm btnD">Delete</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

**Javascript:**

```
     $(".eNew").on("click", function(event){

        $(".tAdd tbody").append(
          "<tr>" +
            "<td>New Selector</td>" +
            "<td><button class=\"btn btn-sm btnD\">Delete</button></td>" +
          "</tr>"
      );





    $(".tAdd tr").click(function() {
      $(".tAdd tr").removeAttr('class');
       $(this).toggleClass("table-active");
    });
```

Also, it works for the original `<tr>` that is in the html file but for some reason when I append a table row it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

This is entirely due to the fact that dynamic content is not bound using the event handler you have declared:

```
$(".eNew").on("click", function(event){
```

Although this will bind to all `.eNew` elements when the code first runs, new elements will not be bound.

Instead, bind to the document and specify `.eNew` as a selector for the click event and it will work:

```
$(document).on("click", ".eNew", function(event){
```

**Edit following OP comment about not working**

Just to verify that your code should now look like this:

```
$(document).on("click", ".eNew", function(event){
    $(".tAdd tbody").append(
        "<tr>" +
        "<td>New Selector</td>" +
        "<td><button class=\"btn btn-sm btnD\">Delete</button></td>" +
        "</tr>"
    );
});

$(document).on("click", ".tAdd tr", function(event){
    $(".tAdd tr").removeAttr('class');
        $(this).toggleClass("table-active");
});
```

Comment: So do I change from ```$(document).ready(function(){``` to ```$(document).on("click", ".eNew", function(event){ ```. or instead do I change where I have ``` $(".eNew").on("click", function(event){ ```?

Comment: @kane_004 No.  Change the line I showed in my answer: `$(".eNew").on...` becomes `$(document).on(...`

Comment: Yeah that is what I thought, however it still does not work. Not sure why

Comment: FYI , I have ```$(document).ready(function(){ ``` on the first tline of the code. Not sure if there is any issue of having   ```$(document)....``` twice.

Comment: @kane_004 There is no issue, you can have it as many times as is you like to